# jQuery code to AngularJS incorporating ngclick and multiple ngclass for css animations

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I am trying to convert the following jQuery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".openNav").click(function() {
      $("body").toggleClass("navOpen");
      $("nav").toggleClass("open");
      $(".wrapper").toggleClass("open");
      $(this).toggleClass("open");
    });
  });
</script>
```

into AngularJS code and here's what I have so far:

http://plnkr.co/edit/LBlKL26c3PP5nBUGWTtQ?p=preview

I can barely get it to work, its a crude animation, but I am not sure what I need to do next.

Here is the original example written with jQuery: http://codepen.io/Lewitje/pen/tyGdf

I would appreciate any insight.

edit:

Possible to add this toggler to make it work??

```
app.controller('test', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$mdUtil',      
'$log', function($scope, $timeout, $mdUtil, $log)  
{$scope.toggle= buildToggler('toggle');

function buildToggler(navID) {
  var debounceFn =  $mdUtil.debounce(function(){
        $mdSidenav(navID)
          .toggle()
          .then(function () {
            $log.debug("toggle " + navID + " is done");
          });
      },300);

  return debounceFn;
}}]);
```

I am running out of ideas so maybe I will add just keep the jQuery but I feel like that defeats the purpose of AngularJS

Comment: What is this code supposed to do, and what is it actually doing?  Does CodePen have a "Run" button?

Comment: Your JSFiddle is very broken. I suggest you try Plunker instead, it supports local script files

Comment: it's supposed to incorporate an animation whereby the wrapper moves towards the bottom right to reveal a navigation menu per the Jquery code pen example...i'm not sure why the example isn't running for you in CodePen

Comment: @RobertHarvey the codepen works for me. Nice animation btw OP :)

Comment: @Phil yeah it's pretty nice which is why i would love to get it to work :p
 `code`

Comment: You really need to check your console for errors before posting your Plunker / JSFiddle examples. Here's one without errors ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/LBlKL26c3PP5nBUGWTtQ?p=preview

Comment: @Phil appreciate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty much there. The classes for the ng-switch were being applied to the wrong elements.

```
$(".openNav").click(function() {
  $("body").toggleClass("navOpen");
  $("nav").toggleClass("open");
  $(".wrapper").toggleClass("open");
  $(this).toggleClass("open");
});
```

This was applying the open class to the body, nav, .wrapper and what was clicked on.

```
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="test" ng-class="{'navOpen':toggle, 'icon':toggle, 'wrapper': toggle}" ng-click="toggle=!toggle">
```

Whereas ng-class in your example were applying the classes all to the body tag.

http://plnkr.co/edit/03cO8o3EYsDt9y0JHQgK?p=preview

Comment: works like a charm, a thousand thanks Garrett, and more important I understand conceptually what I was doing wrong. Thank you much sir.